# Ubuntu black login screen with diamon characters

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

I tried upgarding an old PC from 18.04.5 to 20.04.2
I never succeeded getting to any kind of installation from the USB stick.
But I did manage to destroy probably a lot of things on the way...

Now on startup I can't get to bios settings and I get to a screen like this:

black login screen
[image: black login screen]

and I can't exit it

I'm not sure if I dont remember my username or it's because the diamonds.. (when it did startup until then I didnt need to enter username)

do u know how to fix this?

Thank you!